# Extend Custom UITableViewCell when on iPad

Tags: ios, uitableview, ipad, cocoa-touch

I am using a custom TableViewCell to show some data, but my app is universal and I want to it to fully take advantage of the screen's size. The problem is that it will have the same size it has on iPhone, so it will look like the image I've put below. Any help? It's probably very simple, but I'm new to auto layout and I need a hint. Cheers!

[image: iPad Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I did it myself and all I had to do is set some constraints on the labels and etc.